# How to convert longitude and Latitude into xy location on a 2d world map

Tags: c#

I need to mark an object on a 2d map using c#. The first thing I need to resolve is converting the latitude and longitude of that object into xy location on the map. Does anyone knows how to do that and what's the logic behind the algorithm? How can we make sure a point on the 2d world map is corresponding to a real longitude and Latitude?

Thanks

Comment: Since you specifically mention a 2-d *world map*, I take it you're not interested in approximations that only hold for a small region around a central longitude and latitude.  There are many different map projections that depict a globe as a 2-D map, and we'll need to know which projection your map uses before being able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you are after. We implemented a project using C# and ArcGis Generated Layered Map, but ages ago in school

This might help

- [**Map component for building GIS
  applications**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/gismap.aspx)
- [**Latitude, Longitude, Bearing,
  Cardinal Direction, Distance, and C#**](http://bryan.reynoldslive.com/post/Latitude2c-Longitude2c-Bearing2c-Cardinal-Direction2c-Distance2c-and-C.aspx)
- [**Distance between locations using latitude and longitude**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/distancebetweenlocations.aspx)

A very good, open Source Project at CodePlex:

- [**SharpMap**](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap) is an easy-to-use mapping library for use in web and desktop applications. It provides access to many types of GIS data, enables spatial querying of that data, and renders beautiful maps. The engine is written in C# and based on the .Net 2.0 framework. SharpMap is released under GNU Lesser General Public License.

Answer (score 1):

How about **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908/mapping-latitude-longitude-to-a-distorted-map)** question and answer on SO.